# How to set hive properties from Oozie in global configuration

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

I would like to pass hive set commands into all hql calling in Oozie scripts. I have many hql and I would like to pass the hive parameters to each hql.I used to write all the set commands in each hql file now I would like to keep in work flow level. Can any one suggest If I am doing something wrong.

I have put part of my workflow. when executing the jobs I don't see the hive parameters are not propagated and hence jobs are failing.

```
    <workflow-app name="WF_AMLMKTM_L1_LOAD" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
      <global>
      <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
      <configuration>
                    <property>
                        <name>hive.exec.parallel</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
                        <value>spark</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode</name>
                        <value>nonstrict</value>
                    </property>
                </configuration>
      </global>


<action name="map_prc_stg_l1_load_com" cred="hive2">
        <hive2 xmlns="uri:oozie:hive2-action:0.1">
            <jdbc-url>${hive2_jdbc_url}</jdbc-url>
            <script>${basepath}/applications/stg_l1_load_com.hql</script>
              <param>basepath=${basepath}</param>
              <param>runsk=${wf:actionData(&#39;runsk_gen&#39;)[&#39;runsk&#39;]}</param>
```

Comment: What is the oozie version are you using/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add it as below.

...            `<argument>--hiveconf</argument>
<argument>hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict</argument>
<argument>--hiveconf</argument>
<argument>hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true</argument>`

Answer (score 0):

Put all your hive related configurations in hive-site.xml and pass it with hive action using

```
<job-xml>[HIVE SETTINGS FILE]</job-xml>
```

https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_Hive2ActionExtension.html

Comment: I can't do that as that xml is used by all the project team. This is specific to my workflow or projects.

Comment: @user Try creating a folder with your hive settings and set job.xml this way `<job-xml>myjob/hive-site.xml</job-xml>`. or just name the file `my-hive.xml ` or something.